# How do I change mac address on Ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: wireless, broadcom, configuration, mac, ip

AC68 I can change my mac address on windows with tmac perfectly but on linux I dont see any software with a GUI that can help me, as macchanger doesnt change my mac address it just reverst to the original.

Comment: Have a look on your connection setting. You can easily alter the MAC address.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to dash, search for **Network Connections**.
2. On **Network Connections** window  select your current connection, then click <kbd>Edit</kbd>.
3. Navigate to **WiFi** tab (for WiFi connection) or **Ethernet** tab (for Wired connection).
4. Under Device field, type your desired MAC address on "Cloned MAC Address" field.

[image]

**NOTE:** Change we have applied to MAC Address are temporary, they will be reset after every reboot.

Comment: To make this work on my Ubuntu 16.10 machine I had to disable Wi-Fi, then set the "Cloned MAC address" and after pressing "Save" reenable Wi-Fi.
Might be a hardware/driver issue (Asus Eee PC 1080HA).

Answer (score 0):

It is described here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkAdmin

as yu would do on windows you select "settings" from the start menu and there click on "network".

Answer (score 0):

To change a MAC Address

1. Go to your network connection
2. Right Click network Connection and Choose Edit Connection
3. Choose Wireless SSID
4. Select Edit
   **Add A USB Wifi Card**
5. You will have a selection, choose BSSID (USB Wifi Card)
6. Choose Device MAC Address

You should be OK..